# Rebuilding Parent Widgets Triggers Child's InitState Every Time: Is this Expected Behavior?

Tags: flutter

`We have recently upgraded our flutter project to latest. The previous version was 1.22.1and current is 3.7.6.
After upgrading we are facing an issue with child class widgets. Everytime when the parent class rebuilds, the the child class will call again and initstate is triggered.

Preventing Repeated Initiation of Child Widgets' InitState on Parent Rebuild in Flutter Project Upgrade. Please find my below code. Everytime the status in the bloc changes, the biometric will get triggered. That is, even after login success, the bimetric is triggered.

// Parent class

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
    static const String route = '/login';

    @override
    _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
    @override
    void initState() {
      CountryConfig.instance!.changeCountryCode('');
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            appBar: const Header(
              hideLeading: true,
              hideTrailing: true,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) {
                return LoginBloc(
                  authenticationRepository:
                      RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context),
                );
              },
              child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                  buildWhen: (LoginState prevState, LoginState currentState) =>
                      prevState.status != currentState.status,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
                      return ModalProgressHUD(
                        inAsyncCall: state.status == FormzStatus.submissionInProgress,
                        child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: double.infinity,
                            decoration: styles.bodyBackgroundImage,
                            child: SafeArea(
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                  IconButton(
                                                    icon: Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/icons/login_small_icon.png',
                                                      color: styles.appPrimaryIconColor(),
                                                    ),
                                                    onPressed: () {},
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                            ?.translate('app_login_text') ??
                                                        '',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: styles.appPrimaryTextColor()),
                                                  ),
                                              ],
                                          ),
                                          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0)),
                                          LoginForm(),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                          ),
                      );
                  },
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

// CHild Widget

```
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
  bool isAuthorized = false;
  bool cancelBiometric = false;
  bool showLoginWithTouchIdButton = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
  _getBioMetricPreference();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate() async {
    isAuthorized = false;
    try {
      isAuthorized = await auth.authenticate(
          localizedReason: AppLocalizations.of(context)!
              .translate('login_form__scan_finger_print')!,
          options: const AuthenticationOptions(
              stickyAuth: true, useErrorDialogs: true));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    if (isAuthorized) {
      BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(const BiometricSubmitted());
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
              content: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                  .translate('profile__biometric_failed')!)),
        );
    }
  }

  void closeBiometricPrompt() {
    setState(() {
      cancelBiometric = true;
    });
    auth.stopAuthentication();
  }

  Future<void> _getBioMetricPreference(
      [bool forceShowBiometric = false]) async {
    final bool showWidget = await SettingsRepository.getPreferenceBool(
        Constants.bioMetricPreference);
    final bool firstLogin = await SettingsRepository.checkIfFirstLogin();
    final bool previouslyLoggedOut =
        await SettingsRepository.checkIfPreviouslyLoggedOut();
    if (showWidget && !firstLogin) {
      setState(() {
        showLoginWithTouchIdButton = true;
      });
      if (!previouslyLoggedOut || forceShowBiometric) {
        _authenticate();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
        print(state.status.isInvalid);
        if (state.status.isSubmissionFailure) {
          if (state.apiError.isEmpty == true) {
            BlocProvider.of<ApiResultBloc>(context)
                .add(ApiResultError(state.apiError));
            // context.bloc<ApiResultBloc>().add(ApiResultError(state.apiError));
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
              ..showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                    content: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            ?.translate('login_form__login_error') ??
                        '')),
              );
          }
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                _UsernameInput(),
                _PasswordInput(),                
                _ForgotCredentialLabels(),
                _LoginButton(),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```